# Inicio de sesion para tienda

Tags: php, html, sesiones

Tengo problemas con un proyecto escolar.
Es sobre una tienda pero el inicio de sesion lo agregue en un modal en el index y me redirige a la misma pagina de index pero sin darme pistas de si inicio sesión o no. Si entro como admin no tengo problemas porque son otros directorios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que al iniciar sesion cambie ese modal por otro al iniciar sesion pero no me quiere funcionar.

A este tendría que cambiar el modal con el inicio de sesión activo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include 'views/php/conexion.php';
session_start();
$ID_Usuario = ($_SESSION['ID_Usuario']);
print_r($ID_Usuario);
?>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Chein</title>
    <div class="w3l_login">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal88"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        </div>
</head>
<!-- header -->

<?php

/***************************************************************************************************** */
/* Se necesita validar la sesion activa para que cambie entre el modal de iniciar sesion y el de cerrar */
/***************************************************************************************************** */
if (isset($_SESSION['ID_Usuario'])) {
    echo "
    <div class='modal fade' id='myModal88' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModal88' aria-hidden='true'>
    <div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
            <div class='modal-header'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>
                    &times;</button>
                <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>
                    ¡Usuario!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class='modal-body modal-body-sub'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-md-8 modal_body_left modal_body_left1' style='border-right: 1px dotted #C2C2C2;padding-right:3em;'>
                        <div class='sap_tabs'>
                            <div id='horizontalTab' style='display: block; width: 100%; margin: 0px;'>
Aquí quiero introducir un menu de usuario
                            <button onclick='location.href='views/php/session_close.php'' class='nav_link cerrar' title='Cerrar sesión'> <i class='fad fa-sign-out-alt' style='font-size: 1.5rem'></i> <span class='nav_name'>Cerrar sesión</span></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
    ";
} else {
    echo "
    <div class='modal fade' id='myModal88' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModal88' aria-hidden='true'>
    <div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
            <div class='modal-header'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>
                    &times;</button>
                <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>
                    ¡Inicie sesión ahora!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class='modal-body modal-body-sub'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-md-8 modal_body_left modal_body_left1' style='border-right: 1px dotted #C2C2C2;padding-right:3em;'>
                        <div class='sap_tabs'>
                            <div id='horizontalTab' style='display: block; width: 100%; margin: 0px;'>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class='resp-tab-item' aria-controls='tab_item-0'><span>Iniciar sesión</span></li>
                                    <li class='resp-tab-item' aria-controls='tab_item-1'><span>Regístrate</span></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class='tab-1 resp-tab-content' aria-labelledby='tab_item-0'>
                                    <div class='facts'>
                                        <div class='register'>
                                            <form action='views/php/iniciar-sesion.php' method='post'>
                                                <input name='Email' placeholder='Correo' type='text' required=''>
                                                <input name='Password' placeholder='Contraseña' type='password' required=''>
                                                <div class='sign-up'>
                                                    <input type='submit' value='Iniciar sesión' />
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class='tab-2 resp-tab-content' aria-labelledby='tab_item-1'>
                                    <div class='facts'>
                                        <div class='register'>
                                            <form action='views/php/registrar-usuario.php' method='post'>
                                                <input placeholder='Correo' name='Email' type='email' required=''>
                                                <input placeholder='Contraseña' name='Password' type='password' required=''>
                                                <div class='sign-up'>
                                                    <input type='submit' value='Crear cuenta' />
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <script src='js/easyResponsiveTabs.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
                        <script type='text/javascript'>
                            $(document).ready(function() {
                                $('#horizontalTab').easyResponsiveTabs({
                                    type: 'default', //Types: default, vertical, accordion           
                                    width: 'auto', //auto or any width like 600px
                                    fit: true // 100% fit in a container
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
                        <div id='OR' class='hidden-xs'>
                            O</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-md-4 modal_body_right modal_body_right1'>
                        <div class='row text-center sign-with'>
                            <div class='col-md-12'>
                                <h3 class='other-nw'>
                                    Inicia sesión con</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class='col-md-12'>
                                <ul class='social'>
                                    <li class='social_facebook'>
                                        <a href='#' class='entypo-facebook'></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class='social_dribbble'>
                                        <a href='#' class='entypo-dribbble'></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class='social_twitter'>
                                        <a href='#' class='entypo-twitter'></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class='social_behance'>
                                        <a href='#' class='entypo-behance'></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
    ";    
};
?>
```

Todo esto esta en el header de todas mis paginas de la tienda

```
if (isset($_POST['Email']) && isset($_POST['Password'])) {
    $mail = $_POST['Email'];
    $mail = strtolower($mail);
    $password = $_POST['Password'];
    $password = sha1($password);
    $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE correo =  '$mail' AND password = '$password'");
    while ($print = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
        $type_user = $print['ID_TipoUsuario'];
        $ID_user = $print['ID_Usuario'];
if ($print['ID_TipoUsuario'] == 1) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['ID_TipoUsuario']  = '1';
            $_SESSION['correo']  = $correo;
            $_SESSION['ID_Usuario'] = $ID_usuario;
            header('location:..\..\index.php');
        }
        // Si type_user es 2 accede a admin
        if ($print['ID_TipoUsuario'] == 2) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['ID_TipoUsuario']  = '2';
            $_SESSION['correo']  = $correo;
            $_SESSION['ID_Usuario'] = $ID_usuario;
            header('location:..\admin\index.php');
        }
}
```

Esto es lo que me llevo al iniciar la sesión.

Comment: No entiendo el núcleo de tu pregunta: *pero el inicio de sesion lo agregue en un modal en el index y me redirige a la misma pagina de index. Quiero que al iniciar sesion cambie ese modal por otro al iniciar sesion pero no me quiere funcionar.* ¿Podrías explicarlo mejor? Además, tienes dos redirecciones, a dos páginas llamadas `index` en dos carpetas distintas, dinos a cuál de ellas está yendo. Pulsa en [edit] para aclarar el problema.

Comment: Ya agregue más detalles, espero me entienda. y los index son dos, uno de usuario y otro de admin. El de admin no tiene problema pero el de usuario no me cambia de modal si se supone si paso el inicio de sesión porque igual me recarga la pagina

Comment: Tienes varias preguntas, limítala a un problema en específico. Por favor revisa [ask]

Comment: listo @JheymanMejia , gracias

Comment: y en tu archivo `registrar-usuario.php` donde esta el `session_start();`??

Comment: No tendrás demasiados ```session_start()```, por ejemplo después de que incluyas tu conexión haces un ```session_start();``` y luego en el siguiente código donde dices: **Todo esto está en el header de todas mis paginas** también vuelves hacer ```if ($print['ID_TipoUsuario'] == 1) {  session_start(); }``` intenta quitar este último.